# HTML form: action clarification

Tags: php

Hello I am currently making a registration page,

I'm new to php, and was wondering if this would work when I use the action part in form

```
<form method="post" id="formArea" action="action.php">
```

action.php is a file that contains

```
redirect.html
```

`<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>`

would this work? or is there a way where I can have both in the action section without the need for having to make a new file?

Comment: Sorry, but it is unclear what you ask... What is `redirect.flx`? What is the sense of that output line? And why don't you simply _try_ if that is possible instead of asking us?

Comment: redirect.flx is just an html file. it will redirect the user to the new page and display the information they inputted. I havent tried because I am not home to connect to the server

Comment: Now your question is even more unclear: `action="action.php"` will result in a request to a file `action.php`. Why should a file `redirect.html` come into play? And what good should an additional file do?

Comment: because i would also like to run <?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>   with the same action command but since I can only run one thing through action, i thought i could possible make a file that linked both and both would executed, im not sure if this would actually work however

Comment: A form submission will result in exactly one request to the browser. Same with a link. That can trigger one php file to get executed. What you do inside that script is up to you. You can include hundreds of files, spawn sub processes ot just execute an echo command. As you like.

Answer (score 0):

You Could Just Do This From The Form. If This is what your looking for:

```
<form method="post" id="formArea" action="<?PHP $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>">
//this will make the form post to same page as the form
```

if your wanting to send this to both you can save the `$_POST` Data In A Variable and Use It Later.
EX:

```
<?PHP
//your form submit code might look something like this same file as your form
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    foreach($_POST as $key -> $value)
    {
       //echo or show your values or store your values in database or w/e
       $_SESSION['post'][$key] = $value;
       //this will make a session variable to be used again later each session array is marked with post identified by $key and stored a $value
    }
    //you can call your other page here this will only run after this page runs and loads your information above and then redirect with a session variable.
    header("Location: redirect.html");
}
else
{
    echo "<form method=\"post\" id=\"formArea\" action=\"".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."\">";
}
```

This Code Is Not Tested But It Would Work the redirect.html will process code from `$_SESSION['post']`